# Restore TextView single line ellipsize mode after using multiline scrolling mode

Tags: android, textview

I have TextView with large text. Initially, the TextView displaying as single line, without scrolling and with "..." at the end of the string (`android:ellipsize="end"`):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:text="...some large text..." />
```

Then I expand TextView and add scrolling to it:

```
myTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
myTextView.setMaxLines(10);
```

After that, I compress TextView back to single line, but there is no "..." at the end of the string:

```
myTextView.setMovementMethod(null);
myTextView.setMaxLines(1);
```

I also try to reset ellipsize in the code `myTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END)`. But still no "..." at the end of the myTextView.

So, is there any way to use ellipsized after using scolling mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setSingleLine(true)` instead of `setMaxLine(1)`. I was having the same problem. That was my solution.